# iPhone - Possible to detect bluetooth id from non-mfi bluetooth device?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, mfi

I want to place bluetooth devices in different locations and record when the phone gets into each's range. I realize iphone can only connect to mfi devices but can it find out a device id for non-mfi??

If there is a way, would this pass apples app review? I need this app to be able to get into the app store.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, if you have Bluetooth enabled on the iPhone other devices can connect to it.  In particular they could do SDP queries (or Remote Name Requests or even a RFCOMM connect).

Or if the phone is in Bluetooth discoverable mode the other devices could do device discovery (inquiry) to find it.  (Does the phone stay in discoverable mode when locked?)

Comment: I'm interested in my app being able to detect other non-mfi devices. I am doing to to try to determine the current location based on the distance from the bluetooth and the fixed location of the bluetooth device.

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question whether you want an iPhone app to detect the devices, or the devices to detect the phone.

If you have the former in mind, your requirement is exactly what BtLE's (Bluetooth 4.0/Smart/LE) advertising capability is for. Apple's iBeacon technology is such an implementation, or you might roll your own. It'll allow you to do fine grained location in an iOS6+ app running on 4S, 5, and recent iPads. BtLE advertisement detecting apps will easily pass App store guidelines.

From the other direction, devices with BT 2.x - 4.x radios, or with wifi radios, or with various scanners and software radios, will be able to detect mobile phones, tablets, and other radio equipped devices. How much can be discovered is wildly variable.